# Fill NSOutlineView with two dimensional array data

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmutablearray, nsoutlineview

This has been buggering me for some time now, and I really need to know or this is even possible. And what maybe is the proper approach.

I have a view-based `NSOutlineView` with two columns, another class is taking care of the data parsing. The data-parsing class is returning a two-dimensional `NSMutableArray`. I want fill the first column with the data of the array with index `foo[index][0]` and the second column with the data at index `foo[index][1]`

Up to now I only managed to get the NSOutlineView to display the correct data at the first column, I have no clue how to accomplish filling the second column with my data. The `NSOutlineView` and `NSOutlineViewDataSource` -delegates look like this:

```
- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item {
    return foo.count; // works fine
} 

- (BOOL) outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item {
    return FALSE; 
}

- (id) outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item {
    return !item ? [[foo objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:0] : 0;
}

    - (id) outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
                   if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"column1"]) {
                return item; // Correct data
            }

                if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"column2"]) {
               return // Here i want the data for column 2
            }
}
```

So I guess what is needed is that the delegate `- (id) outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item {}` needs to be build in such a way that `item` already consists of all the 2 dimensional data? But how to accomplish this? Is there a way to also return `item` with the data as followed when the second column needs to be filled?

```
[[foo objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have a second column, you need a single object for that column for each row.  If you have a two dimensional array of objects, and the 1st dimension is rows, and the 2nd cols, you have no children.  So where exactly does the tree structure of the outlineview come into play?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I understand correct: what you're basically saying is that is it possible to add childs per column, instead of rows? How to accomplish that? The Apple documentation only seems to mention the above required delegate methods. If this truly possible I just could add the data per column instead of row by row. But how to adapt the delegate method `- (id) outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item` To do that? Thanks.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you're using an outlineview when your structure is not a tree.  It sort of looks like you're assuming that if `item` is nil, it's the root, and that the root has the arrays foo[0..n] as children.   In which case:  `return !item ? [foo objectAtIndex:index]: 0;`  in method 3 and `return [item objectAtIndex:0]` for column 0 and `return [item objectAtIndex:1]` for column 1.   The row represents the array.  The cols display array objects 0 and 1.  But I still don't get why you're sticking this into a view that displays a tree.

Comment: I see. Actually the structure is a tree. The NSOutlineView is showing a list of directory names in column one, and their corresponding pathExtension at the second column. The data parser I made is designed in such a way it already worries about splitting the data. Nevertheless, your answers has helped me. Thanks a lot ;)